# IBAction on a button in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Using iOS 5 : : : I have a scenario where I must create a tableView with Custom Cells.
The custom cells have a Controller called TainingCellController Subclass of UITableViewCell and a NIB file TrainingCell.xib . While the parent table is placed inside a UIViewController called TrainingController..

Now I am seriously wondering, the relationship of that CustomCell to the File Owner, who receives the IBActions or IBOutlets..

In the Custom Cell NIB file, I can change the file owner (by default set to NSObject) and also can click on the cell itself and change it's class from UITableViewCell to TrainingCellContrller ..

What should be the appropriate classes for these two options ??
Where should the IBActions & IBOutlets be defined (TrainingCellController or TrainingController)?

And what If I need outlets to "labels in custom cell" to be defined in TrainingCellController while button action to be defined in TrainingController??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will set your `UITableViewCell`'s class to your `CustomCell`'s class and you will defined `IBoutlet`s in `CustomCell` class and connect them.

And then you will set your Xib's file owner to your `ViewController`, and in your `ViewController` you will declare an

```
IBOutlet CustomCell *yourClassLevelCell;
```

and connect this `IBOutlet` to your Xib's `UITableViewCell`

now when you will initilize the cell inside your `ViewController's` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will add target manually, something like this:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = yourClassLevelCell;
   [cell.button addTarget:self ... ];  
   //button is IBOutlet in your CustomCell class which you will have
   //connected to your Button in xib
}
```

Comment: Great... All Clutter Cleared..!! =) Thank You Adil ..
By the way, directly connecting the Button IBAction from Custom Cell to File's Owner (the UIViewController) also works..!!

Comment: well, in that case, you cannot use that UITableViewCell in another `UIViewController`, you will have to add target again by code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try working out with dynamic buttons on the same tableView class

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell == nil) 
    { 
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkRequestedCC" owner:self options:nil];
{
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[WorkRequestedCC class]])
            cell = (WorkRequestedCC *)oneObject;


    }

    UILabel *Button=[[UIBUtton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(792, 13, 10, 15)];

    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Button];
}

-(void) ButtonClicked
{
    //your code here
     }
}
```

Comment: Your code example contains two straggling curly brackets (line 6 and and penultimate line). Please correct this code to make it clear.