# how to use custom cell in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to create 4 cell "button or picture" in one row in uiTableView like this picture:

but I don't know how can I do that :

would you please help me!
Thanks in advance!

here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *monKey = @"Monday";
NSString *tueKey = @"Tuesday";
NSString *wedKey = @"Wednday";
NSString *thuKey = @"Thusday";
NSString *friKey = @"Friday";
NSString *satKey = @"Satuarday";
NSString *sunKey = @"Sunnday";

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:monKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:wedKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:tueKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:thuKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:friKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:satKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:sunKey];

[keys addObject:tueKey];
[keys addObject:monKey];
[keys addObject:wedKey];
[keys addObject:thuKey];
[keys addObject:friKey];
[keys addObject:satKey];
[keys addObject:sunKey];



[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd  
target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];    
int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

    UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
    aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];
 //   [aBackgroundImageView release];
}
return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0)
    return @"Monday";
else if(section == 1){
    return @"Tuesday";
}else if(section == 2){
    return @"Wednesday";
} else if(section == 3){
    return @"Thuesday";
} else if(section == 4){
    return @"Friday";
} else if(section == 5){
    return @"Saturday";
}else
    return @"Sunday";

}
```

**Edit 1**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
[cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];

}
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView create 4 square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718414/uitableview-create-4-square)

Comment: to create a Custom cell see this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664622/ibaction-on-a-button-in-custom-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need user interaction, you can add them to a UIView (each is a subview with an appropriate frame), and make the container view the cell's backgroundview.

You can add the views directly to the cell's contentView and get user interaction, but you have to be careful as that area gets modified if there is a accessoryView etc.

Comment: Thanks but I need user interaction

Comment: You get user interaction in the contentView - its just in the backgroundView that you don't normally (maybe a workaround, I just don't know it).

Answer (score 0):

You can design a custom cell with 4 button in Xcode and map them to tableview

Comment: what is the problem you are facing may i know

Comment: Have you tried to add buttons to the table view cells? Show us the code for that.

Comment: i designed custom cell and add them to uitableview not added progrmatically

Comment: @Vinodh this is the whole thing that I have

Comment: @dasdom this is the whole thing that I have

Comment: Then why don't you add buttons to the cell? By the way you are not setting the images of the image views. Therefore your image views don't know what to show.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to design the custom cell and lay out your 4 buttons (since you need user interaction) in interface builder. Here's a very good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) to get you started. Give a tag number to each of the button so you will know which button was tapped later.

Answer (score 0):

want to create 4 cell "button or picture" in one row in uiTableView like this picture:

but I don't know how can I do that :

First of all, you will need to create an objective-c class called MyCell. MyCell will be a subclass of UITableViewCell (this is very important)
In your MyCell.h,

> ```
>   @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
> ```
>
> > ```
> > @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton;
> > @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *secondButton; 
> > @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *thirdButton;  
> > @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *fourthButton;
> >   @end
> > ```

Then in your MyCell.m, just synthesize all those buttons.

In your tableview, where you want to use your customized cell, you need to modify the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. **Replace your UITableViewCell with your custom MyCell**. And don't forget to import "MyCell.h" into that tableview that you are using.

> ```
>     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>         MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>
> if(!cell)
> {
>     cell = [[MyCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
> ```
>
> reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>       }
>
> ```
> [cell.firstButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
> [cell.secondButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
> // and so on.. til you set all your four buttons.
>
> return cell; }
> ```

And from there, your tableview should be showing your custom cell.

Comment: what if you had 52 buttons you should create 52 ??

Comment: use a for loop to create but selector should be a same method and add i as to button with tag you differentiate button